# Can adjust intensity LED before take picture in UIIimagePickerController in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uislider

I building app open Camera by using `UIImagePickerController` but I want before take picture, I can adjust intesity of LED. I think if can add UISlider to `UIImagePickerController` to adjust intesity LED before take picture is good but I don't know how to add `UISlider` to `UIImagePickerController`.

Do you have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

CGFloat brightness = 0.5;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);

```
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Original image
[image drawInRect:imageRect]; 

// Brightness overlay
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:brightness].CGColor);
CGContextAddRect(context, imageRect);
CGContextFillPath(context);

UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
`You can change brightness overlay color to get proper results.`
```